# SQL Unresolved Object to an Object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm trying to create a view with an INNER JOIN:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MatchingTeamNames]
AS SELECT  [XMLSoccer-Team].[ID] AS SoccerID, [XMLSoccer-Team].[Name] AS SoccerName,
            [Smarkets-Team].[ID] AS SmarketsID, [Smarkets-Team].[Name]
FROM [XMLSoccer-Team], [MatchingTeamIDs], [Smarkets-Team]
INNER JOIN [MatchingTeamIDs] ON [MatchingTeamIDs].[XMLSoccerID] = [XMLSoccer-Team].[ID]
```

I am receiving an error for the last part of the INNER JOIN: `[XMLSoccer-Team].[ID]`

> SQL Unresolved Object to an Object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this? implicit and explicit join syntax's together? **DON'T** ever do this!

Try this query with the explicit join syntax:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MatchingTeamNames]
AS SELECT  [XMLSoccer-Team].[ID] AS SoccerID, [XMLSoccer-Team].[Name] AS SoccerName,
            [Smarkets-Team].[ID] AS SmarketsID, [Smarkets-Team].[Name]
FROM [XMLSoccer-Team]
INNER JOIN [MatchingTeamIDs]
 ON [MatchingTeamIDs].[XMLSoccerID] = [XMLSoccer-Team].[ID]
INNER JOIN  [Smarkets-Team]
 ON (The Relations between this tables Smarkets-Team and the table its connected to)
```

Comment: The Statement `FROM a,b` is equivalent to `FROM a CROSS JOIN b`, not `a INNER JOIN b`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. Again, I'm not sure why you got a down vote for this. Maybe an explanation between implicit and explicit join? I'm still not sure why I would not include the other tables in my FROM case

Comment: @SQLGeorge Yes, but thats not the case and you could have seen that if you paid attention to the table names!

Comment: I downvoted not for the answer itself, but because the difference between `cross join` and `inner join` was not explained. That way, someone could be misleaded to think that `a,b`is the same like `a inner join b`, while it is not. It is equivalent to `a cross join b`.

Comment: @GlennCooper In general, don't use implicit join syntax(comma separated) ever! but if you do, don't mix them up with explicit joins because it will raise problems.. Your problem was that you joined to the same table twice, both with the inner join and the implicit join(MatchingTeamIDs)

Comment: @SQLGeorge Oh, so what you are saying is that you downvoted a correct answer, because it wasn't formatted as you want it to be? I answered the OP question, and people should learn from this to never ever ever involve both implicit and explicit join's together!

Comment: No, I downvoted because you implicity said that a "comma join" is the same to an `inner join`, but this is not true. A comma join is is equivalent to an `outer join`, not to an `inner join`. Please make an edit and I will remove the downvote.

Comment: @SQLGeorge comma join is exactly the same as inner join! if you don't specify a join condition its exactly the same as select * from a inner join b on(1=1) so YES, its the SAME

Comment: @sagi, no it is **not**  !! A `cross join` is the full cartesian product !!

Comment: IT PROVIDE THE SAME RESULTS! @SQLGeorge